# ngStorage safe to use?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-storage

I just have a simple doubt about ngStorage. When I use **ngStorage** `$localStorage` or `$sessionStorage` all objects and keys are obviously readable in the browser development tools.

How ever I wonder if there is also a way to actually manipulate them on the fly?

If I for example, save some session params for a user in `$localStorage` is it possible to just WRITE over the `$localStorage` with the Browser Dev Tools or via console and update. manipulate the storage during I have the site open?

Comment: Yes, this is true. You can change everything on client side.

Comment: sure. you can use your console or any other JS to change the values in these storages. In terms of security I'd say that they are even less secure than a cookie (since you can flag cookies to not be writable by JS), but these storages provide more space than a cookie

Comment: And it is not a good idea to save security relevant credentials on the client.

Comment: General rule of thumb when it comes to web security: you don't control anything that's on the client-side. If someone's determined to mess around with the internals of your front-end, or send you malicious requests, they can.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use $localStorage or $sessionStorage for data you don't want a user to manipulate himself. A regular user has access to the same tools as you, so yes he can simply open his developer console and edit whatever is in the $localStorage or $sessionStorage.

You should use ngStorage for things like preferences, a user can edit this as much as he wants, but obviously you'd have a more convenient interface in your application.